# Columnstore index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

is there any way to create Columnstore index in PostgreSQL?
and afterward how to combine it with partition and cluster index?

Comment: Postgres has no built-in column store. You need to use an extension like Citus to get that. And do you mean with "cluster index"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently standard postgresql has no built-in column store, but there is an edition of postgresql called citus which lets you create postgresql with columnstore indexes.

Citus is a distributed/clustered database and if am not mistaken you can create only one database per instance, so this is a limitation. There is also the cloud managed instance called Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL.